# Save a value for later use in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am programming a test case in Selenium IDE and I find the following problem:
I have the following ID
Id = lblInfo The operation (35) has been successfully generated.
The number (35) is logically varying depending on the number of operation that is created. I need to somehow extract the number between () for later use.
I have tried using the storeText command

But as you see in the example it only takes the id = lblInfo and not the rest of the message (The operation has been successfully generated (35))

- storeText
- id = lblInfo
- myVar

How can I do in this case ??

Comment: You'll have to do some actual programming to extract the number you want. In `selenium-ide` I believe you would export the code into the language of your choice, and then manipulate it from there. That being said I haven't done much manual manipulation of `IDE` scripts so there might be an easier way I'm not aware of to edit the code. You can search for how to extract an `int` from a `string` for your language and find plenty of examples. Long story short, you have some limitations with `selenium-ide`, which is why people use `selenium-webdriver` for more robust suites.

Answer (score 1):

Man you can get the number using regular expression like

```
COMMAND      TARGET                                     VALUE
StoreEval   StoredVars['Your_variable'].match(/\d+/)   new_variable
```

You will get 36 in new_variable (you can name it anything)